# Pseudo-random number generator for c++ application

Tags: c++, random

I need a pseudo-random number generator for a c++ application, that will return me the same values in an number interval [0, 20] every time I execute the application. The requests are applied inside a loop while the application is running. For debug reasons, I need a deterministic sequence of numbers.

Thank you very much in advance

Comment: `"return me the same values"`, then why are they called random numbers?

Comment: What's wrong with the `<random>` standard library facility?

Answer (score 4):

The output of `rand` is pseudo-random, which means that it looks effectively random, but is computed the same way each time, starting from a special value called the seed. With the same seed value, you get the same sequence of random numbers.

To set a different seed, use the standard C function void `srand(unsigned int)` once in your code before you start generating random numbers.

Also take a look at:

- [C++ random function return same numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14901078/c-random-function-return-same-numbers)
- [Why do I get the same result with rand() every time I compile and run?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1783629/why-do-i-get-the-same-result-with-rand-every-time-i-compile-and-run)
- [rand function returns same values when called within a single function c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6729214/rand-function-returns-same-values-when-called-within-a-single-function-c)
- [rand() generating the same number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13500494/rand-generating-the-same-number)

Answer (score 1):

You just need to use the same seed for the random function each time.
For example :

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main ()
{
  const int seed = 3;
  /* initialize seed, with the same seed each time: */
  srand (seed);
  printf ("%d %d %d\n", rand()%20, rand()%20, rand()%20);
  return 0;
}
```

Thus, you'll have the same sequence each time.

Answer (score 0):

Seed the random number generator with a known value i.e. `srand(42)` (the meaning of life)

Then use `rand`.

http://linux.die.net/man/3/rand

The maths to get in in the desired range